Compiling Ruby C API (cross-platform)
The include statements presented here corresponds to the values of RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"] and RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyarchhdrdir"], so I thought using RbConfig to setup the compilation will give me much better results when compiling on different platforms. I wrote the following Makefile with the prior in mind:
librb    = $(shell ruby -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]')
archdir  = $(shell ruby -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyarchhdrdir"]')

CC      := gcc -std=c23
EXEC    := test
SRCS    := src/[a-z]*.c
LIBS    := -I$(librb) -I$(archdir) -Lruby
CFLAGS  := -g -Wall -Wextra -Woverflow -Og -pedantic

$(EXEC): $(SRCS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
        @echo "Compiled CRuby $(shell ruby -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["ruby_version"]')"

Which on my system results in:
gcc -std=c23 -o object_test src/main.c -g -Wall -Wextra -Woverflow -Og -pedantic -I/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I/home/user/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/include/ruby-3.2.0/x86_64-linux -Lruby

The ruby header files seems to be linked correctly but I still get undefined reference compilation error for ruby symbols like ruby_init and ruby_cleanup when compiling following code.
#include <ruby.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ruby_init();
  //...
  return ruby_cleanup(0);
}

I know that my question may seem a duplicate of this one, but the links are broken there and it's outdated by 13 years. I am most concerned about ruby > 3.1 for my project.

You are confusing library paths and compiler paths.  When you use -I you want compiler flags not linker flags.  Library paths are for linking libraries.  I don't know anything about Ruby or RbConfig::CONFIG but presumably there's a configuration option like rubyincludedir or similar.  You should use that with -I.  The rubylibpath should be used with -L (library search path).

Changing -I to -L results in the same error.

Changing -I to -L is just one thing, and not the important thing.  You have to find the correct path to add with -I.  The path provided by rubylibpath is the wrong path: that's the path you use with -L, but you still need to add the right path with -I.

You make me confused now. I add the directories mentioned in the Ruby C API guide with the -i flag and the link ruby (-lruby). Ain't that exactly what you say? RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyarchdir"] and RbConfig::CONFIG["rubylibdir"] are not library files, they are directories.

They are directories, yes: they are directories where the linker looks to find library files (like -lruby: that tells the linker to link in the ruby library).  The -L option(s) provide directories where the linker looks to find the ruby library.  But, the COMPILER is looking for header files (text files that are included by your source code), not libraries.  Like, ruby.h.  The compiler looks for header files in directories prefixed with -I.  Header files are in different directories than library files, so using library directories with -I won't help: those are the wrong dirs.

You. have to use some other command to find some other configuration value to find the directory to look for header files.  I don't know Ruby so I can't tell you what it is.  It will be something like: $(shell ruby -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyincludedir"]') but maybe rubyincludedir is wrong: you have to find out for yourself or from someone else what the right name is.  Then, you put the result of that command, which will be the directory to look for header files like ruby.h, with the -I option on your compile line.

I try to maintain docs for this process in my Ruby C API Guide.
At minimum, the C compiler needs to find three things:

The general Ruby header
The platform-specific Ruby header
The Ruby C lib

Depending on how you set up Ruby and your C compiler, these could already be in standard locations where your compiler can automatically find them. At worst, you need to specify the locations of all three. Using RbConfig to find them is a great idea, you're just not doing it quite right. The correct config keys are:

rubyhdrdir to be used with -I to add an include path
rubyarchhdrdir to be used with -I to add an include path
libdir to be used with -L to add a linker path (and -Wl,-rpath, if you need to add a runtime search path as well)

So here's an example of a Ruby script that outputs all of the compiler options you need:
require 'rbconfig'
require 'shellwords'

rblib = RbConfig::CONFIG['libdir']

# location of ruby.h
puts "-I#{Shellwords.escape RbConfig::CONFIG['rubyhdrdir']}"
# location of ruby/config.h
puts "-I#{Shellwords.escape RbConfig::CONFIG['rubyarchhdrdir']}"
# location of libruby
puts "-L#{Shellwords.escape rblib}"
# add libruby location to runtime library search path
puts "-Wl,-rpath,#{Shellwords.escape rblib}"
# link with libruby
puts "-lruby"


Ow, I rushed with accepting the answer but did not really get time to run the compiled program yesterday. Now I see that it returns a realtime error: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.3.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. This is really weird as I see that file at the directory pointed by RbConfig::CONFIG['libdir'].

I have edited the answer to include the realtime library search as well.
